# Docker-compose: using with selinux

Tags: docker-compose, centos7, selinux

While working with docker on Centos and selinux to mount volume we have to use `:z` 
something like

`docker run -ti -v /home/my-file.txt:/tmp/my-file.txt:z alpine sh`

However how could we use same functionality via docker-compose

Answer (score 6):

One way I found is to use

```
   flask:
        build: .
        container_name: flask
        volumes:
           - {src_folder}:/<target>:z
```

Comment: how to write this with :z in long syntax for volume definition ?

Comment: I thought :z does not work anymore in recent docker versions. https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label